# How to convert the Varchar of sum to time using sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, time

i wrote the stored procedure like this

```
Declare @sum varchar(50)
Set @sum = (select SUM(ct.WorkingHours) 
            from ConsultantTimeSheet ct 
            where ConsultantID = @Consultantid 
              and ct.Status = @status 
              and ct.StartDate = @StartDate 
              and ct.EndDate = @Enddate 
            group by ConsultantID)
```

Now I got the sum like `33.90`, but I have to display `34.30`, how to convert like that format minutes exceed 60 add to hours.

Comment: how do you get 33.90? is that a decimal field?

Comment: varchar field Declare @sum varchar(50)

Comment: What is WorkingHours datatype?

Comment: **WHY** is `@sum` a `varchar(50)` variable if you plan to store a numerical value in it? It should be `decimal` - even `float` is a bad choice (rounding errors!)

Comment: decimals don't work well for times. remember there re 60 minutes in an hour, not 100 and they don't always convert nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SUM VARCHAR(50)='33.90';

SELECT CAST(CAST(LEFT(@SUM,CHARINDEX('.',@SUM,0)-1) AS INT)+
       CAST(SUBSTRING(@SUM,CHARINDEX('.',@SUM,0)+1,LEN(@SUM)) 
                                    AS INT)/60 AS VARCHAR(10))+'.'+
       CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@SUM,CHARINDEX('.',@SUM,0)+1,LEN(@SUM)) 
                                         AS INT)%60 AS VARCHAR(10))
```

**result**:

```
34.30
```

Comment: This doesn't actually address the summing of hour.minute values from the table. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

You're in for a world of hurt with storing times as decimals. The way I see it, your times are stored in decimal form, therefore 1hr 30 mins is going in as 1.3, correct?

You're expecting 33.90 to turn to 34.30 due to .90 meaning 90 minutes, however, have you considered the collossal failure in the storage format beyond that trifling problem?  Consider this scenario:

```
create table ConsultantTimeSheet (WorkingHours decimal(5,2));
insert ConsultantTimeSheet select 1.3;
insert ConsultantTimeSheet select 1.3;
insert ConsultantTimeSheet select 1.3;
insert ConsultantTimeSheet select 1.5;
Declare @sum varchar(50);
Set @sum = (select SUM(ct.WorkingHours)  from ConsultantTimeSheet ct);
select @sum;

--- output
5.40
```

Because .40 is not above 60, there's no conversion. But, it should really be 6 hours 20 minutes!!

Anyway, to work with what you have, you'll need this. Please, fix your db structure at the earliest opportunity.

```
Declare @sum varchar(50);
Set @sum = (select 1.0*floor(RawDecimal)+(RawDecimal-1.0*floor(RawDecimal))*60/100
            from (
            select RawDecimal=sum(1.0*floor(WorkingHours)) + sum(WorkingHours-floor(WorkingHours))/60*100
            from ConsultantTimeSheet ct 
            where ConsultantID = @Consultantid 
              and ct.Status = @status 
              and ct.StartDate = @StartDate 
              and ct.EndDate = @Enddate ) x);
select @sum;

--- output
6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider your approach as it's a presentation issue and not a database issue.

Comment: how to handle the issue pls give me example

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your field Type , it seems that the sum itself is incorrect because you should sum the decimal part of the field in 60 minute base not 100 minute base and i think that the sum will return the wrong answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select (Hr+MinFraction/60)+((MinFraction%60)/100.00)
From
(
    Select Cast(HourMimute AS INT) As Hr,Cast((HourMimute%Cast(HourMimute AS INT)) *100 As 
    Int) As MinFraction
    From
    (
      select SUM(ct.WorkingHours)  As HourMimute 
        from ConsultantTimeSheet ct 
        where ConsultantID = @Consultantid 
          and ct.Status = @status 
          and ct.StartDate = @StartDate 
          and ct.EndDate = @Enddate 
        group by ConsultantID
    ) As tmp1

  ) AS tmp2
```

Better you can write a function which will convert the 100 hour minute format to 60 hour minute format. I have just included in the query itself